# Save part of a terminal output

Tags: command-line, bash, gnuplot

I am using Ubuntu to get the output from a BLE device, and in the terminal I get a continuous stream of values. The only problem is that they are preceded by a useless string (I'm reading characteristics of the BLE device so they have a "Notification handle = 0x000c value: FF FF"). I only need the hex string at the end for my data.

Currently I log the terminal output window using script and then from the created text file, I extract the hex values and convert them into voltages which I then plot. However, I have to actually perform both of these commands, so I'm effectively taking screenshots of the data.

I'm wondering if there was some way to only write the hex values into a .dat file and manipulate them, because then I can actually plot the data in real time. If you guys know any alternative to obtain a graph of the data in real time, do let me know.

Comment: Please give us an input example and what result you expect for that. [edit] your question to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options you can try:

```
yourcommand | sed 's/.*: //' > file.dat

yourcommand | cut -d: -f2 > file.dat

yourcommand | awk -F: '{print $2}' > file.dat

yourcommand | grep -Eo '[[:xdigit:]]{2} [[:xdigit:]]{2}$' > file.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the output per line trough awk like following:

```
echo "Notification handle = 0x000c value: FF FF" | awk '{print $6, $7}'
```

which will result in this output:

```
FF FF
```

another pipe would allow you to put that into a file by appending

```
echo "Notification handle = 0x000c value: FF FF" | awk '{print $6, $7}' | tee -a values.dat
```

This would leave you with a file containing always a two byte hex value per line from which you could then move on.